# incredible program crash call stack

Tags: c

I have one incredible segment crash call stack in C, could anyone help me out?

```
int function(struct A *a) 
{
    ... some other declare
    struct B *b = a->b;
    int count, len;
    ... some other declare
    struct C *c = b->c;  /* not crash here */
    ....some other decalre

    if (b->e) { /*crash log indicate b is NULL and crash here,first line instrucment code*/
    .....
    }
    ....
}
```

My question is why the crash did not happened at the `struct C *c = b->c`.

GCC is the compiler.

Tony

Comment: Have you seen anything that will guarantee a "crash" in documentation?

Comment: Accessing invalid pointers is Undefined Behaviour. The compiler is not obliged to guarantee a crash as soon as UB is encountered. By definition UB means the behaviour is unpredicatable.

Comment: What's an incredible segment? I'd like to know more about these!

Comment: The code following if (b->e) will use the c. If the b is one null pointer, I think it should crash at the c = b->c , not at the following code, I met such crash before with the same compiler parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler does not guarantee ordered execution of instructions unless there is a data flow dependency. It has numerous optimizations, one of which is [data flow optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler#Data-flow_optimizations).

Also, if you don't use the variable `c` at all, the compiler will optimize it out of the code ([dead code optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination)) and you may not see a crash at all (if the rest of the program works fine).

One easy way to understand which optimization is happening is to access the `c` variable somewhere. Another way is to disable optimizations (`-O0` in GCC).